# Distributed critical section in web-farm

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mutex, critical-section

I have about 50 web-sites, load-balanced across 5 web-servers. They all use Enterprise Library Caching, and access the same Caching database. The items in the Caching database are refreshed every few hours, using an ICacheItemRefreshAction implementation.

I want to guarantee that only one web-site ever refreshes the cache, by putting the refresh code in a [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section).

- If the web-sites were running in a single app-pool on a single server, I could use a [lock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- If the web-sites were running in separate app-pools on a single server, I could use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

However, these will not ensure the critical section across multiple web-servers.

Currently, I am creating a new key in the caching database to act as a mutex. This will **generally** work, but I can see a slim chance that 2 processes could enter the critical section.

```
public class TakeLongTimeToRefresh : ICacheItemRefreshAction
{
    #region ICacheItemRefreshAction Members

    public void Refresh(string removedKey, object expiredValue, CacheItemRemovedReason removalReason)
    {
        string lockKey = "lockKey";
        ICacheManager cm = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();

        if (!cm.Contains(lockKey))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Entering critical section");
            // Add a lock-key which will never expire for synchronisation.
            // I can see a small window of opportunity for another process to enter
            // the critical section here...
            cm.Add(lockKey, lockKey, 
                   CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null, 
                   new NeverExpired());

            object newValue = SomeLengthyWebserviceCall();
            cm.Remove(removedKey);
            Utilities.AddToCache(removedKey, newValue);

            cm.Remove("lockkey");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way of having a **guaranteed** critical section to ensure I don't call the web-service twice?

**EDIT** I should add that I can't use a shared file, as the deployment policies will prevent it.

StackOverflow references:

- [Will lock() statement block all threads in the proccess/appdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997438/will-lock-statement-block-all-threads-in-the-proccess-appdomain)
- [Sharing cache between multiple web-sites.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274703/sharing-cache-between-multiple-web-sites)

Comment: Maybe some kind of Token ring system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to involve some external lock acquisiton common to all. For example, a table t in SQL with one row and one lock field where you will acquire a lock with:

```
set transaction isolation serializable;
update t set lock = 1 where lock = 0;
```

check rows affected and if its 1 you have the lock, release it by updating lock to 0. This essentially piggybacks on SQLServer's row lock, if two start at the same time only one will gain U lock after S lock, the other one will block and subsequently return 0 rows affected (since the first transaction flipped it to 1).

Comment: I think this is the right approach. If EL Caching threw an exception if you added an existing key, than that would have the same effect. However, as it doesn't, I need to implement it myself in SQL. Thanks :)

Comment: Just keep in mind that this locking is not durable, if your process faults after acquiring but before releasing the lock, it will stay permanently locked. A good way to wiggle out of that is to enforce timeouts, meaning if lock is not released in set time a requester can obtain it even if lock=1, something like 
`set lock=1, locktime=getdate() where lock = 0 or datediff(m,  locktime, getdate()) > 15` for 15min

Comment: @mmix Thanks for your suggestion. I'm using it. The only problem is that I think the datepart "m" is for months and not minutes. Minutes would be "mi". Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move the logic for creating/returning a lock handle to database and **combine** them and this will guarantee it is always one process having the lock.

So the database could have a stored procedure which you ask for a lock, and either it will return empty result (unsuccessful) or will create a record and return it.